# Copy scrape data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am using the below code to scrape a piece of data from a web page.

```
Sub Scrape()

Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", Range("M4"), False 'Cell that contains hyperlink
    .send
    HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

'Add New Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "ESTIMATE"


'Scrape Description
HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName ("div")
Debug.Print HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText
End Sub
```

The last line `Debug.Print HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText` prints the text (it's a sentence) I require in the Debug screen without any issues.

The problem I am having is copying that data to a specific cell on a different sheet. I have tried the following to no avail:

```
HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName ("div")
text = HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText
text.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("L4")
```

Also I have tried:

```
Dim test As Range
HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName ("div")
Set text = HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText
text.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("L4")
```

And Also:

```
HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName ("div")
HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("L4")
```

Each time I get an error when trying to copy saying 'Runtime 424: Object Required'

Any advice on how to resolve this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying shouldn't be used here at all. Try filling the cell value instead. Plus you haven't declared the variable `text`, that's why you get object required error. Your code should read:

```
Dim text As String
text = HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("p")(0).innerText
Sheets(1).Range("L4").Value = text
```

Answer (score 3):

A faster method would be to use a css selector and method that returns a single node as opposed to a collection

```
Worksheets("SheetNamweGoesHere").Range("L4").Value  = HTML_Content.querySelector("p").innerText
```